# Flex item position above other flex item at shrink

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this example. If you srhink the screen you will see that the green box positions under the red one.

Question:

Is it possible that the green box appears above the red box? I want the green box to be at the right side and then appears at the top if the screen size is too small

```css
.box {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: wrap;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  height: 850px;
  width: 250px;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried it with `wrap-reverse` but the block appears at the bottom on begin

I am also open to other solutions maybe with newer technologies like `grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rememberd i can use something like `margin: auto` that pushes elements all the way back.

So i used `flex-flow: wrap-reverse`. My green box is now on the bottom. To push it upwards i used `margin-bottom: auto`. Auto on vertical works because its inside an flex container

```css
.box {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: wrap-reverse;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  height: 850px;
  width: 250px;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this with `order: [numeric value]`.

If you add a media query to this where it should happen (in this example screen viewport lower than `640px`, the HTML order can stay the same. You just add order as a hierarchy element. `.b` will be shown first, because a higher ranking. Read more about [order at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .a {
    order: 2;
  }
  .b {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

***EDIT***

With CSS changes on `.box` it's possible. Add `flex-flow: column wrap` to the media query and it will work. It will then go for vertical alignment (column).

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  height: 850px;
  width: 250px;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  .a {
    order: 2;
  }
  .b {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you open the screen fullscreen and go to 640px the 2 boxes swap its position and if you shrink it more then the green box appears at the top. thats not 100% what i wanted but it gives me an idea. i was looking for something more dynamic

Comment: thank you for your answer i really appreciate it but  I have figured out myself how to do it without media queries.